# suitable work environment for .htacces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat

I came across a conversation while working with .htaccess.I'm developing .htaccess for my current project a senior porgrammer said that the .htaccess will work perfectly in linux-based systems rather than windows. Is this true...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Htaccess files will work in most webservers. Their function is not dependent on the os.